# If a question belongs on another site, how do you access the "standard migration path"?

Tags: support, migration

I tend to answer a lot of questions on `R` as I am primarily an R programmer. Since `R` is a statistical programming language, a lot of questions end up being predominantly about statistical methodology rather than programming, and so I tend to try and flag those to be moved over to CrossValidated instead of here.

I've been doing this by using the "In need of moderator attention" flag lately because I haven't been able to consistently see / get a choice within the other options to say "This question belongs on CrossValidated". However, my last few flags were turned back by a moderator with the note "Stats is on the standard migration path, use that instead of flagging for moderator attention".

How do you access the standard migration path within the choices when you flag? I see the choices as follows:

- spam
- rude or abusive
- should be closed...
- a duplicate...
- very low quality
- in need of moderator intervention

Which one of these leads to the migration path? Or am I missing something here? And how long until I can flag again?

Comment: Should be closed > Off topic > belongs on another site of the Stack Exchange network. No crossValidated option though..

Comment: @JonasCz When I follow that path, [Cross Validated is the bottom choice](http://i.stack.imgur.com/UJIJq.gif).

Comment: @BilltheLizard I think the confusion is that it's called "stats.stackexchange.com", instead of the site name "Cross Validated".

Comment: @ryanyuyu That's most likely the problem, if everyone is shown the same list. (I'm 99% sure they are, but sometimes things change.)

Comment: @BilltheLizard, Oh, did't see it.. Was browsing on my phone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Flag it for closure to migrate it.

Comment: What reason for closure? "Off-topic?"

Comment: @TARehman: Yes. It has to be off-topic here, or it really should not be migrated at all.

Comment: @TARehman Is the question in fact off topic?  If so, then that sounds like a good place to look.

Comment: I guess the confusion is that I didn't think of migration as a form of closure. But now that I know I can do it right. Is there any reason that CV might not show up (for instance, does it only show up for some languages?)

Comment: @TARehman No.  Its behavior is site wide.

Comment: @TARehman Just because a question might be appropriate for migration doesn't mean it is off-topic. Please separate the idea of migration from the idea of closing.

Comment: I can't; the site equates the two of them together.

Comment: @nhgrif The rule of thumb with migration is _don't migrate_ unless the question is off-topic on the source site. If there's just another site it could belong on yet it's on-topic on the source site, you aren't supposed to flag for migration. If you read the comment from Deduplicator, they already pointed this out. In other words: A question is not appropriate for migration unless it is off-topic. So the ideas do indeed go together.

Comment: @Kendra Hmm, perhaps they do, but to say "this *could* be migrated, therefore it is somehow off-topic here, so what close reason should I use?" Is absolutely the wrong mindset.